# How to DROP_LATEST with coroutine Flow<T>?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Please help. I was trying to do:

```
    2sec     2sec     2sec
------[A]------[B]------[C]------...----------------> InitailFlow
       \        |        | 
        \      drop      drop
         \
     5sec \    5sec        5sec
----------[1]---------[2]---------[3]-----|> AnotherFlow
result: [A1, A2, A3]
```

So I have InitailFlow which emits a short amount of time (2 seconds) which is then transformed to AnotherFlow which takes longer to finish (15 seconds in total)... I would like to drop the other incoming items emitted by the InitialFlow while AnotherFlow isn't finished...

I've tried:

```
flow{
    delay(2000)
    emit("A")
    delay(2000)
    emit("B")
    delay(2000)
    emit("C")
}.buffer(0, BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)
    .onEach {
       println("Event for $it")
    }
    .flatMapConcat {
       flow {
           delay(5000)
           emit("${it}1")
           delay(5000)
           emit("${it}2")
           delay(5000)
           emit("${it}3")
        }
     }
     .onEach {
         println(it)
     }
     .launchIn(scope)
```

But for some reason this is the result:

```
Event for A
A1
A2
A3
Event for B
B1
B2
B3
```

It still process `Event B` for some reason even when I have a `.buffer(0, BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)`.

Why does it still process Event B?

Is there a way to do this? I expect the output to be only:

```
Event for A
A1
A2
A3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which coroutines version are you using? I believe I am using the latest yet I can't find the  `.buffer(0, BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)` function...

Comment: @Deadbeef It was added in 1.4.0

Comment: I don't really get what output you expect. Could you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: @Deadbeef its 1.4.0-M1

Comment: @marstran Sure! I added the expected output... its also the same output as the "graph" in my question.. So just to clarify a bit more... I would like that as long as the othr flow in the `flatMap` isn't finished yet... all other incoming events must be dropped.. if the `flatMap flow` finishes, it could then again take another event...

Comment: You can get kind of close using the `conflate`-operator. But that will cause it pick up the last element emitted from the outer flow when the first inner flow is completed. It will give you `A1 A2 A3 C1 C2 C3`. This is just equivalent to using "DROP_OLDEST" instead of "DROP_LATEST" in you buffer-call though.

Comment: The reason you get the B-events when using DROP_LATEST is because the strategy only decides which element to keep when there already is a value waiting for the conflated buffer. So with DROP_LATEST, B is suspended waiting for A to complete, then you choose to keep B when C comes in because C was latest. With DROP_OLDEST, you choose to keep C because B was the oldest.

Comment: @marstran, i see... that make sense.. hmm... but i feel like my usecase is pretty much valid and should be supported.. dont you think? is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.dropIfBusy(): Flow<T> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val channel = produce(capacity = Channel.RENDEZVOUS) {
            collect { offer(it) }
        }
        channel.consumeEach { emit(it) }
    }
}
```

This is basically the "naive"  `buffer` implementation from the [kotlin docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html)
The only difference here is that we use `channel.offer` instead of `channel.send`
When used in conjunction with a RENDEZVOUS Channel, all values that are offered to the channel, while it is suspended, are dropped, creating your desired behavior.

Comment: Haven't tried yet but if this works shouldn't this be the implementation of `.buffer(RENDEZVOUS, DROP_LATEST)` anyway? coz RENDEZVOUS == 0.

Comment: I initially thought so myself, however the docs state "To implement either of the custom strategies[DROP_OLDEST/ DROP_LATEST], a buffer of at least one element is used."

Comment: Clever solution, but this doesn't really work either. I'm getting this output: `Event for A, Event for B, Event for C, C1, C2, C3`. I think it's because this function will emit all events from the upstream flow before continuing with the `flatMapConcat`.

Comment: Have you replaced `.buffer(0, BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)` in your code with `dropIfBusy()`? I get the expected output using that

Comment: If this still doesn't work, it might depend on the context. What Dispatcher does `scope` use?

Comment: I could confirm that this solution works.. but I still find it confusing as to why this is the case... in my opnion `.buffer(RENDEVOUS, DROP_LATEST)` must work this way. Don't you guys agree? I filed an issue in the coroutine github here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2391. Hope they see and respond to it.

Comment: @AdrianK Sorry, I just realized I still used some code from a previous attempt. Now I got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with @AdrianK's solution for a bit, I actually found a simpler solution using `channelFlow`. Due to `channelFlow` currently being experimental API, you have to opt in to use it though.

Like this:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.dropIfBusy(): Flow<T> = channelFlow {
    collect { offer(it) }
}.buffer(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function `flatMapConcatDropLatest` (needs a better name)

```
fun <T, R> Flow<T>.flatMapConcatDropLatest(transform: suspend (value: T) -> Flow<R>): Flow<R> {
    return flow {
        channelFlow {
            collect { upstreamValue ->
                trySend(upstreamValue)
            }
        }.buffer(0).collect { upstreamValue ->
            val downstreamFlow = transform(upstreamValue)
            downstreamFlow.collect() {
                emit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the custom operator that should work.
It is important to use `trySend()`, and not `send()`

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.dropIfBusy(): Flow<T> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val channel = produce {
            collect { trySend(it) }
        }
        channel.consumeEach { emit(it) }
    }
}
```

However, what about using a `Channel` instead of your initial Flow?

See the example below that uses `produce` to create a channel (with a default buffer size of 0).

```
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {

    produce {
        delay(2000)
        trySend("A")

        delay(2000)
        trySend("B")

        delay(2000)
        trySend("C")
    }
        .consumeAsFlow()
        .onEach {
            println("Event for $it")
        }
        .flatMapConcat {
            flow {
                delay(5000)
                emit("${it}1")
                delay(5000)
                emit("${it}2")
                delay(5000)
                emit("${it}3")
            }
        }
        .onEach {
            println(it)
        }
        .launchIn(this)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Everytime `emit` is called it gets suspended so the `buffer` operator has no effect.

I'm not sure about the output you're expecting to have but I think you're looking for the `conflate` operator:

```
flow{
    delay(2000)
    emit("A")
    delay(2000)
    emit("B")
    delay(2000)
    emit("C")
}
.conflate()
.onEach {
    println("Event for $it")
}
.flatMapConcat {
    flow {
        delay(5000)
        emit("${it}1")
        delay(5000)
        emit("${it}2")
        delay(5000)
        emit("${it}3")
    }
}
.onEach {
    println(it)
}
.launchIn(scope)
```

The `conflate` operator official documentation states:

> Conflates flow emissions via conflated channel and runs collector in a
> separate coroutine. The effect of this is that emitter is never
> suspended due to a slow collector, but collector always gets the most
> recent value emitted.

You can find the `conflate` operator official documentation [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/conflate.html).

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, using `conflate` does not achieve what OP wanted to do.

Comment: conflate doesn't work.. doesn't drop the LATEST value.. it drops the OLDEST...
Here is the docs: "/**
         * Requests a conflated channel in the `Channel(...)` factory function. This is a shortcut to creating
         * a channel with [`onBufferOverflow = DROP_OLDEST`][BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST].
         */"